# How to detect llvm::ConstantInt is signed or unsigned?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

how could I detect llvm::ConstantInt is signed or unsigned ?

Which API should I use?

Comment: [isNegative()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html#a2a8c8be274f3bd351e083ab3828c14c7) is the closest you can get. LLVM's type system doesn't distinguish signedness much, because assembly operations such as  add/sub/cmp don't. This is really a special case of 'how can I distinguish between two things that are different in my source language but not in typical assembly output?'

Comment: @arnt I will try to use some alternative solution to solve it.

Comment: @linrongbin, did you find any solution?

Comment: @bbv, I don't rely on information of LLVM, I create a symbol table to register the type of symbols.